# Why is “She requested that he raise his hand” the correct sentence, not “She requested that he raised his hand”?

Tags: subjunctives

I'm reading about the subjunctive mood and i have trouble grasping the following sentence from [https://data.grammarbook.com/blog](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/subjunctive-mode-and-some-confusing-words/):

> She requested that he raise his hand.

I have understood that with verbs besides were, past perfect tense should be used with the subjunctive mood.

1. Is the verb **raise** really past perfect or am I missing something?
2. Is the following variation of the original sentence grammatically correct?

   > She hoped that he raise his hand.

Comment: The second should be `She hoped that he would raise his hand`.

Comment: When you ask someone to do something, they haven't done it yet. So you can't use past tense, as in "he raised his hand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is the verb raise really past perfect or am I missing something?*

> Since statements in the subjunctive mood exist outside time, tense
>   applies differently. The tenses of the indicative verbs could change,
>   and the subjunctive verb indicating the imagined action would not
>   change

Examples:

> I **wish** I were there to have a drink with you and dish.
>
> I **wished** I were there to have a drink with you and dish.
>
> She **demanded** that he leave the hospital premises.
>
> She **will demand** that he leave the hospital premises.

Source: [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/)

---

*Is the following variation of the original sentence grammatically correct?*

Accourding to this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/163352/37242)

> *She hoped that he raise his hand.

isn't correct because

> In English, we do not generally use the subjunctive with the verb hope